# delete a cell and shift cell up if it have some word in cell

Tags: excel

[image]

Your see a sample.json in C

i want to delete and cell up If have a sample.json in C
It possible  ?

Comment: Use the [AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844%28v=office.11%29.aspx) if you intend to delete the entire row. If you only want the cell in column C deleted (shifting all cells below it up and breaking data synchronization) then use VBA and start at the bottom and work up.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really intend to remove word sample.json in column C for all occurrences even it breaks data synchronization or you want to retain data synchronization. Solution depends on this parameter.